# How to block a program from accessing the Internet on Centos

Tags: centos, firewalld

I want to block a program from using internet. I don't want this program to use internet. How can I do that.

Comment: using iptables https://serverfault.com/a/550278

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the program as specific user (or group), you can use iptables to filter the traffic to prevent access:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m user --user <user> -j DROP
```

Filtering by (primary) group works similarly by replacing `--user <user>` with `--group <group>`. If you add your regular user to your no-internet group, you can run the application in that group using `sg`. A step-by-step answer is provided in [serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/550276/how-to-block-internet-access-to-certain-programs-on-linux/550278#550278).

Firewalld uses iptables to implement the firewall. Iptables rules can be added by using [*Direct Interface*](https://firewalld.org/documentation/direct/options.html).